# How to login from admin login page and others should login from another login page in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

In users table i have admin , editor and blogger i want admin can login from different login page than editor and blogger login page and i have to two login pages and all users exist in users table but blogger or editor shouldn't login from admin login page and same for admin admin should prevent to login in editor and blogger login too and after logged in for admin , editor and blogger for all users redirect me to admin panel , only different login from should have , how can make this please help .

Tip : I have distinguished users by type not role

[image: users table image]

**admin-login.blade.php**

```
@include('layouts.app')


    <div class="sufee-login d-flex align-content-center flex-wrap">
        <div class="container">



            <div class="login-content">
                <div class="login-logo">
                    <a href="{{ route('login') }}">
                        <img class="align-content" src="{{ asset('others') }}/{{  $shareData['admin_logo'] }}" alt="">
                    </a><div style="color: white; text-align: center;">Admin Login</div>
                </div>
                <div class="login-form">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }} <!-- means you are still using middleware--> <!-- before--><!-- admin.login.submit -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Email address</label>

                             <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Remember Me
                            </label>
                            <label class="pull-right">
                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                    Forgot Your Password?
                                </a>
                            </label>

                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-success btn-flat m-b-30 m-t-30">Sign in</button>
                        <div class="register-link m-t-15 text-center">
                             <br>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="{{ asset('admin/assets/js/vendor/jquery-2.1.4.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/assets/js/popper.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/assets/js/plugins.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/assets/js/main.js') }}"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

**login.blade.php**

```
@include('layouts.app')


    <div class="sufee-login d-flex align-content-center flex-wrap">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="login-content">
                <div class="login-logo">
                    <a href="{{ route('login') }}">
                        <img class="align-content" src="{{ asset('others') }}/{{  $shareData['admin_logo'] }}" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="login-form">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }} <!-- for multiple exception-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Email address</label>

                             <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Remember Me
                            </label>
                            <label class="pull-right">
                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                    Forgot Your Password?
                                </a>
                            </label>

                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-success btn-flat m-b-30 m-t-30">Sign in</button>
                        <div class="register-link m-t-15 text-center">
                            <p>Don't have account ? <a href="{{ route('register') }}"> Sign Up Here</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="{{ asset('admin/assets/js/vendor/jquery-2.1.4.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/assets/js/popper.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/assets/js/plugins.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/assets/js/main.js') }}"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

**LoginController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/back'; // redirect to back page

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

**AdminLoginController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;

class AdminLoginController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout'); //who want to have access to this  // before //$this->middleware('guest:admin');

    }


    public function showLoginForm()
    {


        return view('auth.admin-login');

    }


    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate the form data
         $this->validate($request, [
        'email'   => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6'
      ]);

        // Attemp to log the user in
         if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)) {
        // if successful, then redirect to their intended location
        return redirect()->intended(route('admins')); // we redirected them where they wanted to go  // admin.dashboard  // route('admins'); should be same with ->name('admins'); in page of web 
      }


        // If unsuccessful, then redirect back to the login with the form data
        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }


}
```

Comment: how do you determine if a user is an admin or a blogger without them being logged in yet?

Comment: I have used laravel-permission package with permission and role table to determine user what roles they have

Comment: Can't you return view based on condition in showLoginForm()? like `showLoginForm(){return isAdmin ? view('auth.admin-login') : view('auth.login');}`

Comment: leave the AdminLoginController.php , can i do this in original LoginController.php ?

Comment: yes you can there is a `showLoginForm()` in `AuthenticatesUsers` trait that is used in the `LoginController`. You can override this showLoginForm in your LoginController and return the view conditionally.

Comment: I have posted an answer to show how to do it in LoginController. Check it out

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding `showLoginForm()` in your `LoginController` like this:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return $isAdmin ? view('auth.admin-login') : view('auth.login');
    }
}
```

Comment: But how can the system check this is admin or not while i have distinguished users by " type " in users table , while i have tested error said  "undefined variable isAdmin"

Comment: thats what I asked you in the first comment. How would you check if they are admin or blogger without them being logged in yet? You said you were using a package or something

Comment: As i said i have distinguished users by type in users table

Comment: then you cant check the role before login. You cant show the login based on a user's role if you don't even know who the user is. The user needs to be authenticated first for you to check if he is admin or blogger.

Comment: please can you come to my pc using teamviewer or anydesk to show you what i have ?

Comment: contact me at https://join.slack.com/t/vue-vmr4432/shared_invite/zt-eau36fgx-k1KWjR7fmNdqfvlJouderw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213526/discussion-between-andria-and-uzair-riaz).